# Sort Parent Elements by criteria of Child Elements with JavaScript and / or TinySort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, tinysort

I have a series of list items in the following structure. I am trying to use Tinysort to sort the list items of the ordered list class="collection-grid editable ui-sortable". The criteria for sorting is the text in double stars below which is the text of div class collection-item-title.

```
<div id="collection-items" class="collection-items">
<ol class="collection-grid editable ui-sortable">
<li class="collection-item-container track_play_hilite subscriber-item initial-batch  active editing">
<div class="collection-title-details">
<a href="https://sts9.bandcamp.com/album/20190907" class="item-link">
<div class="collection-item-title">
**2019.09.07 :: Red Rocks Amphitheatre :: Morrison, CO**
</div>
</a>
</div>
</li>
<li class="collection-item-container track_play_hilite subscriber-item initial-batch  active editing">
<div class="collection-title-details">
<a href="https://sts9.bandcamp.com/album/20190906" class="item-link">
<div class="collection-item-title">
**2019.09.06 :: Red Rocks Amphitheatre :: Morrison, CO**
</div>
</a>
</div>
</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

What I have so far is the following:

```
tinysort('ol#collection-grid editable ui-sortable>li',{selector:'div.collection-item-title'});
```

This doesn't seem to work. I am open to any methods that will work an I am not limited to Tinysort.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the below function to sort the items correctly.

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
        var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
        return (vA > vB) ? -1 : (vA < vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}

sortUsingNestedText($('.collection-grid'), "li", "div.collection-item-title");
```